# Perl: Using hash instead of array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

```
while ($word = <STDIN>) {
    $length = length($word) -1; # Subtract 1 for included newline char
    $wordLength[$length]++;
}

print "Word length \t\t Occurrences \n\n";

for ( my $i =1; $i <= $#wordLength; $i++ ) {
if (not exists $wordLength[$i]) {
    print "$i \t\t\t 0 \n";
}
    else {
    print "$i \t\t\t $wordLength[$i] \n";
    } 
}
```

This works great reading in a txt file and outputting as such:

```
Word Length  Occurrence
1            27 
2            104 
3            1039 
4            3505 
5            7181 
6            11765 
7            15898
```

I am trying to get this to work using hash instead of an array but it doesn't seem to work. This is my attempt:

```
while ($word = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($word);
    $length = length($word);
    $wordLength{$word} = "$length";
}

foreach $word (sort keys %wordLength) {
    print "$word, $wordLength{$word}\n"; # print key and value
}
```

Comment: Why not `$wordLength{$length}`? It's super odd you're keying on word now.

Comment: If you still want counts of each length, then you only need to change the brackets from your original code: `$wordLength[$length]++` becomes `$wordLength{$length}++`.

Comment: Also, "it doesn't seem to work" is not a valid problem description. What is your code actually doing? How is that different from what you expect?

Comment: Can you please clearly state what you need?  If it is the output shown under "_This works great reading_" then your hash attempt clearly has nothing to do with that.  You are storing _words_ as keys (not lengths) and you aren't counting.  (Is this a homework by any chance?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Any array works great here.

```
my @occurrences_by_length;
while (my $word = <>) {
   chomp($word);
   my $length = length($word);
   ++$occurrences_by_length[$length];
}

print "Length  Occurrences\n";
for my $length (1..$#occurrences_by_length) {
   my $occurrences = $occurrences_by_length[$length]
      or next;

   printf "%6d  %11d\n", $length, $occurrences;
}
```

A hash, while less efficient, could easily be used with next to no changes.

```
my %occurrences_by_length;
while (my $word = <>) {
   chomp($word);
   my $length = length($word);
   ++$occurrences_by_length{$length};
}

print "Length  Occurrences\n";
for my $length (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%occurrences_by_length)) {
   my $occurrences = $occurrences_by_length{$length};
   printf "%6d  %11d\n", $length, $occurrences;
}
```